# How to lazy instantiate a list in a stream lambda function?

Tags: java, concurrency

I want to create `CompletableFuture`s of a list. For any failing element, I want to collect the element that failed in a  separate list (for further processing).

Problem: the 'error collection' has to be `final` in order to add elements inside the lambda expression.
But most of the time, I won't have any exceptions and thus instantiation of the list is just useless.

```
//just an example list to illustrate
List<Integer> list = Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, 4, 5);

List<Integer> errors = null; //non final

List<CompletableFuture<Integer>> futures =
            list.stream()
                    .map(i -> CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(
                            () -> {
                                if (i % 2 == 0) throw new RuntimeException(i); //dummy business logic exception
                                return i;
                            })
                            .exceptionally(ex -> {
                                if (errors == null) errors = new ArrayList<>(); //TODO: invalid as written
                                errors.add(i);//TODO: invalid as written
                                return null;
                            })
                    )
                    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Question: is that possible somehow?

Comment: just instantiate `errors` with an empty list. what's the problem? 
`final List<Integer> errors = new ArrayList<>();`

Comment: What is the performance boost you get from lazy initializing the list?

Comment: Yeah but if most of the time I would not need the list, I'd want to not instantiate it beforehand (if possible). Could be like 10 calls per second approx. I mean, why should I create unused objects if not absolutely necessary? So i could also free up the garbage collector at bit.

Comment: Lambdas are supposed to be stateless; by conditionally creation of a `List` or not you're introducing a state. It's just not what they're intended for.

Answer (score 1):

A workaround solution: can't you use the initial `List<Integer>` also as *errorsList*?

Remove from the `List` all those elements that fulfill your business condition.

```
List<CompletableFuture<Integer>> futures = list.stream()
    .map(i -> CompletableFuture.supplyAsync( () -> {

          synchronized (list) {
              // not a dummy business error
              if (i % 2 != 0) {
                  list.remove(i);
              }
          }
          return i;
     })).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

At the end, the `list` will contain only the *errors*. And you won't have another empty unused `Collection`, which bothers you.

Note that won't work with `Arrays.asList(T...);` as it returns an `java.util.Arrays.ArrayList` instance, which is unmodifiable.

I personally do not like this solution though:

- use of `synchronized` block
- use of `synchronized` block **inside lambda**
- removal of element in `List` while iterating without the use of `Iterator`
- Using the same Object for two different purposes

Comment: didn't even try the code I wrote, but I do realize now the `synchronized` block may even be unnecessary...

Answer (score 0):

The only way I could get this to work was to make the error list a private static ArrayList that had Objects as elements.  Going about this way means a lot of suppressed warnings.  By doing it this way, I was able to get 2 and 4 in the errors list.  I hope this helps!

```
public class Main {

private static ArrayList<Object> errors;

public static void main(String[] args) {

    //just an example list to illustrate
    List<Integer> list = Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, 4, 5);

    List<CompletableFuture<Integer>> futures =
                list.stream()
                        .map(i -> CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(
                                () -> {
                                    if (i % 2 == 0) throw new RuntimeException(i.toString()); //dummy business logic exception
                                    return i;
                                })
                                .exceptionally(ex -> {
                                    if (errors == null) errors = new ArrayList<>(); 
                                    errors.add(i);
                                    return null;
                                })
                        )
                        .collect(Collectors.toList());

    System.out.println(errors);
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

I found a way using `BiConsumer`:

```
BiConsumer<Throwable, Integer> handler = new BiConsumer<Throwable, Integer>() {
    List<Integer> errors;

    @Override
    public void accept(Throwable throwable, Integer i) {
        if (errors == null) errors = new ArrayList<>();
        errors.add(i);
    }

    public List<Integer> getErrors() {
        return errors;
    }
};
```

Usage in the stream:

```
...
.exceptionally(ex -> {
                handler.accept(ex, i);
                return null;
            })
```

Answer (score -1):

you can do that with a method.

```
   List<CompletableFuture<Integer>> futures =
            list.stream()
                    .map(i -> yourFunction(i)).(Collectors.toList());
```

...

```
    public CompletableFuture<Integer> yourFunction(CompletableFuture<Integer> i){
...
    }
```

it is not much practice but works

Comment: Sorry, but I don't see where this is different to my approach. (except you encapsulated `CompletableFuture.supplyAsync()` into `yourFunction()`...). This has nothing to do with the `final` variable.

Comment: i understand, but i had the some need and this was the way i found.
your list should be local